# ASP.NET MVC - How to dowload the .wmv file into our local file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to download the file from server file to out local file system of type (.wmv) video file using Asp.net MVC pattern.

The files are existed in the Server File system in a cetain folder. The correponding file name existed in our local database.

Using Server's file system path + filename(.wmv) have to store into my local file system. please send me the links or code.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
public void Open()
{
    var serverfilepath = "some logical path";
    var filename = "some file name"; 

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.HeaderEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
    Response.ContentEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
    var fi = new FileInfo(serverfilepath);
    if ( fi.Exists )
    {
        using( var fs = fi.OpenRead() )
        {  
             // you should really buffer this...
             var bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
             fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
             Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
         }
    }
    Response.End();
}
```